# How do I get the current HTML element on which the event handler is being called

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get a reference to the HTML DOM element inside its event handler that I am wiring up?

```
var dashboard =
    {
        WireHandlers : function()
        {
          $(".approveButton")
            .unbind("click")
            .click(dashboard.approve)
        },

        approve : function()
        {
          // In here, I would like a reference
          // to the HTML DOM element that was clicked

          // Also, I would like its id
        }
    }
```

Comment: See http://javascript.info/tutorial/obtaining-event-object  then https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add an argument to your `approve` function (typically named `event`) and call `currentTarget` on it:

```
approve : function(event) {
  // In here, I would like a reference
  // to the HTML DOM element that was clicked
  event.currentTarget

  // Also, I would like its id
  event.currentTarget.id
}
```

Note that you can also use `this` within the `approve` method to reference the clicked element.

```
approve : function() {
  this // or $(this) if you want to use jQuery
}
```

---

Note that in this case `target` and `currentTarget` are interchangeable. However, in more complex scenarios, [there are important differences between the two](http://www.qc4blog.com/?p=650).

Comment: Thank you very much. :-)

Comment: I added the answer to your second question too (`id`).

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this)
```

is the jQuery element (`this` is the DOM element)

`this` will not be bound to `dashboard` (as you're just providing the function as a callback, you'll have to use eg `dashboard.WireHandlers`)

Comment: Thank you very much. :-)

Comment: I actually like your answer better because its jQuery and that's shorter and sweeter, but I am marking the other answer as the right one as that too is the correct answer and it came a bit earlier. I wish I could mark more than one answer as the right one.

Comment: I'll add that part to my answer so that people have the full answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the jquery documentation here:
https://api.jquery.com/click/

you can access the acted upon element through the "this" variable:

```
  approve : function()
        {
          var elem = this;
          var id = elem.id;
        }
```